# Iframe shareable with entire organization

Tags: iframe, video

We have an internal site that firm members can upload content to. We want users to be able to insert iframes for videos that can be viewed by the entire firm. Sharepoint allows you to get a link that is sharable to the entire organization. However I have not been able to find if there is the same option available with the copy and paste iframes. I would like there to be an option to copy an iframe that can be viewed by anyone, but for iframes, it seems that you still need to share the video with every single person for them to view it.

Is there a way around this?